# MySQL WHERE IN Query

Tags: mysql, sql

there is feeds and likes tables, first i query data from feeds table then try to get likes for likes table for fetched feeds.

feeds table:

```
`feed_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`feed_postid` INT(15) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`feed_type` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
`feed_userid` INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`feed_privacy` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`feed_uids` TEXT NULL,
`feed_title` VARCHAR(180) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`feed_content` TEXT NOT NULL,
`feed_dateline` DATETIME NOT NULL,
```

likes table:

```
like_id
like_userid
like_type
like_postid
```

now i want query form likes table such

```
IN((1, 'status'),(2,'image'),(3, 'status'))
// IN((like_postid,like_type),(like_postid,like_type),(like_postid,like_type))
```

example query:

```
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE like_postid = 1 AND like_type = 'status' OR like_postid = 2 AND like_type = 'image' OR like_postid = 5 AND like_type = 'status';
```

now i want rewrite top query with IN function

```
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE like_postid, like_type IN((1,'status'), (2,'image'), (5, 'status')); --but this is not work, there is any way to do this?
```

Comment: uhmm the question is *slightly* unclear, what do you mean by two conditions? can you give example?

Comment: Try to provide some sample rows and your expected output from a good query.

Comment: example records with desired result can help us understand your question better `:D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

```
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE (like_postid, like_type) IN ((1,'status'),(2,'image'),(5,'status'));
```

Answer (score 1):

this is one of the query to perform top N analysis check it

SELECT * FROM likes WHERE like_type in ('status','image') order by like_postid limit 2
union all
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE like_type in ('status','image') order by like_postid offset 4 limit 1